# Is there a way to figure out what version of Xilinx was used to create a bitfile from looking at the bitfile?

Tags: xilinx

Is there a way to figure out what version of Xilinx was used to generate a bitfile just by looking in the bitfile?  I've opened the bitfile in a hex editor, and only see the project name, date, and fpga model.  See below.

[image: Bitfile header]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible, though this is not official: http://home.earthlink.net/~davesullins/software/bitinfo.html its README contains the following chunk.

Bitinfo is a simple utility that parses the header of a Xilinx bit file
  and outputs all the information that can be obtained from that header. 
  This information includes the Xilinx FPGA the bit file was created for,
  the NCD file the bit file was created from, the creation date and time,
  and the bitstream length.

I guess you have to fallback on wildguess based on date/time. Good luck.

Comment: Wah wah wah...  That's what I was expecting.  It was worth a shot though, Thanks.